# scrapy how to properly export to json

Tags: python, json, scrapy, export

I'm using scrapy to crawl a bunch of websites then export all the items stored throughout the process in a json file. This is how my output looks:

```
[
{ json formatted stuff....
{...
{...
{...
{...
}
][
{more json formatted stuff...
{...
{...
{...
{...
}
]
[
{even more json formatted stuff...
{...
{...
{...
{...
}
]
```

This is not the form I want it in. I know that scrapy processes requests asynchronously, but this output seems wrong for some reason. I don't want there to be square brackets between the chunks of items that are being exported to the json file. All the items I scraped are actually being exported, but shouldn't they all be contained within one pair of square brackets? Should I be exporting this using an item pipeline instead? I'm running the spider from my script, so I just included the feed settings in the CrawlerProcess command. This is how I'm exporting the items:

```
process = CrawlerProcess({
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
    'FEED_URI': 'result.json'
})
process.crawl(FirstSpider)
process.crawl(SecondSpider)
process.crawl(ThirdSpider)
process.crawl(FourthSpider)
process.crawl(FifthSpider)
process.crawl(SixthSpider)
process.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. You have to use 'FEED_FORMAT': 'jsonlines' if you want to export a bunch of items into json format. Hopefully this saves some people the headache it was causing me...